# Unable to use an Edimax EW-7811UN USB Wi-Fi adapter as a Mac 802.1x hotspot

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

I’m having some trouble trying to set up a Wi-Fi hotspot on my Mac using an Edimax EW-7811UN USB adapter

Essentially what I’m trying to do is connect my Chromecast to the network but Chromecast does not support the 802.1x authentication.

I set about trying to create a hotspot with my Mac so that the Chromecast could connect to it.

I have created a VPN network and connected to it then hoped to share it through my Mac to the Chromecast. Due to the Mac’s built in network card already receiving from the modem, I am tryin to use an Edimax EW-7811UN USB adapter hoping that it would share the VPN connection.

However I have had no luck: the VPN and everything can connect fine but the usb adapter only seems to want to connect to any Wi-Fi networks and doesn’t seem interested in sharing my VPN connection.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't open up their Wi-Fi APIs to third-party adapters, so there's no way for OS X's Internet Sharing feature to put your third-party adapter into AP mode.

One solution would be to switch the roles of your two wireless interfaces. Have your USB dongle connect to your existing AP, and have your build-in card create a network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i actually never thought of ding it the other way around. Do you know of any usb dongles that actually connect to a 802.1x network? I'm not sure this one does